# How to display Document Set contents on a page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-set, wiki, welcome-page

Is there any way of displaying the documents inside a Document Set in another page?

What I would like to do is display (maybe through a Web Part) the contents of a Document Set in a page inside a Wiki Library. And when people want to add a new document related to that page then it would be added to that Document Set.

It is a Wiki with software projects and I have a page for each project. I also have a Document Library with folders hierarchically organized with the name of each project and I'm displaying the contents of those folders in the wiki project page with a Web Part.

I would like to start taking advantage of the power of Document Sets metadata to replace the folders and get them displayed in the wiki page but I haven't found a web part to do this.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Do you need documents from Document Set or Document Library (with metadata filtering) on your wiki page?

Answer (score 0):

This would best be accomplished using a Page Viewer web part.

Simply set the page viewer web part's properties such that it displays the document set welcome page for the desired document set.

Answer (score 0):

On the Site Content Types page, click the name of the Document Set content type you want to configure. Under Settings, click Document Set settings. In the Welcome Page section, click Customize the Welcome Page. In the window that opens, click the Site Actions menu, and then click Edit page.

This May Help,
Peter